# get URL before submit form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I wanted to submit a form post based on user input, but the url only works for previous button. How do I take it so the addr.url becomes the current URL instead of the previous click. I want to get the url before I submit the post request.

```
<form id="launch" ngNoForm action="{{addr?.url}}" target="user.name" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="process" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="user.cookie"/>
<button (click)="onSubmit(userInfo)">
<img src="../../../image/clickme.png">
</button>
</form>

onSubmit(userInfo) {
  console.log('post submission' + userInfo);
  this.paymentService.launch(userInfo).subscribe(data => {
    this.addr = data;
    if (this.addr && this.addr !== undefined && this.addr.url && this.addr.url !== undefined) {
        console.log ('url: ' + this.addr.url);
        $('#launch').submit();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: As the url is part of the data you receive after the http request, you need to do the http request before submitting the form.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?   Are you using jquery?  "$('#launch').submit();" makes me think so however your question doesn't say anything about using jquery.

Comment: in angular 2 I have a button I want to do the following...1) get url address when clicked. 2) send the post request with that url address.

Comment: I am using jquery and angular yes. (service subscribe is used to get the url)

Comment: This is not normally the way to submit form data using `Angular`. Try removing the `action` and `method` from the form tag and using Http services instead of jquery. Let us know and we can provide examples/links to how to do this "the Angular way"

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of posting data to a server "the Angular way":

The form tag:

```
<form novalidate
      (ngSubmit)="save(signupForm)">
```

The submit button:

```
      <button type="submit">
        Save
      </button>
```

The save method in the component:

```
  save(signupForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(signupForm.form.value);
    // Call an http service to post the form values.
    this.dataService.post(signupForm.form.value).subscribe();
  }
```

The dataService:

```
  post(signupValues): Observable<Product> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(this.url, signupValues, { headers: headers });
  }
```

NOTE: This code was written without assistance from a text editor and may contain syntax errors.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. The service is different from the form post completely. The service is only to get the url from other component. I need the url to be sent to the post request after user clicked the button because I dont know what url to direct user to.

Comment: What url are you referring to? Maybe you could build a stackblitz to better demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I cant build it in stackblitz because the service is a custom service. Basically the service would fetch a specific url from the database based on the userInfo.id then the url will be returned to the frontend and will be used as action for the form post. My problem is getting the url on the click because when you first click the initial url is undefined, because it is calling the service and try to do the form post at the same time. I would want the service to be returned first before executing the form post.

Comment: I would take the time and implement things as @DeborahK has prescribed.  Just because you can submit the form in pure javascript and circumvent Angular's service's concept and HttpClient doesn't mean you should.  The next developers will thank you if you take the time to build out the proper angular constructs to facilitate this (I know I would...)  You get much better clarity, testablity, and thus maintainability using this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try adjust the fitting. +1 for the effort

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the way DeborahK suggested and inside the onSubmit() function, I would combine both http requests (the one getting the url and the actual submit) with RxJS. E.g. this.httpServe.getUrl().pipe(flatMap(result=>this.httpService.submitWithUrl(result, formValued).